# What may be the disadvantages of enable content expiration in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

What may be the disadvantages of enable content expiration in IIS 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main disadvantage will be that IIS will stop caching components by `modified date`. and whenever you'll change the content of any component, you'll have to hit `ctrl + F5` in order to forcefully get the new content.

one solution to this problem can be appending a querystring to your static components, and that querystring should by dynamic and confiugrable so that whenever you change your contents, you'll only need to change the querystring and your problem will be solved.

following is the example of a dynamic querystring

```
http://google.com/style.css?version=2.1
```

Comment: does IIS reset force browser to flush their cache?

Comment: no, actually IIS sends a header with an expire date, and browser caches the component and does not request for new one until that date. therefore, you'll have to use `ctrl + F5` to forcefully clear the cache and get the new component.

Comment: ok thanks, the content expiration is applicated only on the js, css or for all the content (html tag...)

Comment: yeah, all the `static components`.